# Android - strange Checkbox behaviour

Tags: android

I got the following problem: In my Android App I am using a table to show some information. This information also contains 2 boolean values which are displayed as a checkbox. When the table is loaded the checkboxes work as they should but as soon as I change the interface orientation both checkboxes get checked even if the data values are false.

The table is defined like this:

```
<TableLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/table_properties"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#ffffffff"  
/>
```

And a single boolean row in that table:

```
<TableRow
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>   
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
        android:id="@+id/text_jobprop_name" 
        style="@style/text_list_black"      
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="12dp"         
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:singleLine="false"  
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/table_property_name_background"  
        android:layout_weight="0.7"     
        android:layout_width="0dp"
    />  
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"   
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:background="@color/white">
        <CheckBox
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"      
            android:id="@+id/chckbox_jobprop_value" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:clickable="false"   
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"                    
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

And in the onCreate method of the activity I call a function that sets all the values for the table. I know that this function is called everytime I change the interface orientation but I debugged it and the data values do not change.

Any hints, ideas, whatever?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And in the onCreate method of the activity I call a function that sets
>   all the values for the table. I know that this function is called
>   everytime I change the interface orientation but I debugged it and the
>   data values do not change.

That's true but try putting the setting of the checkboxes in the onResume method... If not: when is your super.onCreate called?

Comment: A thousand thanks, this solved it for me too :)  I hear elsewhere that onRestoreInstanceState might work as well.  Still - weird behavior, and hard to search for :/

Answer (score 1):

Try like this..

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
// This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
// killed and restarted.
 savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean1",cb1.isChecked());
 savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean2",cb2.isChecked());
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

and in onCreate get the values like this..

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 .....
 boolean myBoolean1 = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean1");
 // now check its value and put the value in your checkbox..
```

now it will work as expected I think...